# HTML/JQuery Tab Switching on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, tabs

I need help with switching tabs, here is the example link: http://app.seed-ville.com/357-2/#1

This is just the head part I'm not sure there's anything wrong with it.

```
  <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>


    ----------


    <section id="tab_panes">
    <div class="tab_pane active">Hello</div>
    <div class="tab_pane active"></div>
    <!-- we'll copy/paste the other panes -->
    <div class="tab_pane"><img class="alignleft" src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/40Ly3VB.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="tab_pane">Hi1</div>
    <div class="tab_pane">Hi2</div>
    <div class="tab_pane">Hi3</div>
    </section>


    ----------
```

This is most likely where the problem is.  I'm not sure if I'm calling and executing it correctly on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

$(function() {

    $('.nav a').on('click', function() {

        var $el = $(this);
        var index = $('.nav a').index(this);
        var active = $('.nav').find('a.active');

        /* if a tab other than the current active
        tab is clicked */

        if ($('nav a').index(active) !== index) {

            // Remove/add active class on tabs
            active.removeClass('active');
            $el.addClass('active');

            // Remove/add active class on panes
            $('.tab_pane.active')
                .hide()
                .removeClass('active');
            $('.tab_pane:eq('+index+')')
                .fadeIn()
                .addClass('active');

        }
    });

}());
</script>
```

Possible error in .redactor function being called

```
/* Ready function */
sprout.ready = function($) {
// WYSIWYG
$('.redactor, #gb_deal_description, #gb_deal_highlights, #gb_deal_fine_print, #gb_contact_merchant_description').redactor();
jQuery('.masonry_loop').masonry({
itemSelector: '.loop_deal',
gutterWidth: 15,
isAnimated: true,
isResizable: true,
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting, I can't seem to get the tabs to switch between each other.

Comment: It also cuts this off: <script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script
 type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {

Comment: Are any jquery scripts you wrote executing as expected on the page? Or are all of them broken?

Comment: your javascript code is not correct on page everyline is having br tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the index of parent `li` elements, note that there is a syntax error in your code. If you want to avoid conflict in your page you should pass jQuery as a parameter to a self-invoking function.

```
(function($){

    $('.nav a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('.active').removeClass('active')
        var ind = $(this).addClass('active').parent().index()

        $('.tab_pane.active').hide().removeClass('active');
        $('.tab_pane:eq('+ind+')').addClass('active').fadeIn();
    });

})(jQuery)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLQV8/

Comment: Ok I will try this.  Hope it works.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
function($){
$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
    var ind = $(this).addClass('active').parent().index()

    // Remove/add active class on panes
    $('.tab_pane.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('.tab_pane:eq(' + ind + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn();

});​

Comment: It works on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dLQV8/1 but it doesn't work on the page still. Darn.

Comment: @user1790251 Do you see any error on browser's console?

Comment: Inspecting with Firebug seems to show no errors.

Comment: However, SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
[Break On This Error]  

function($){<br />

/357-2/ (line 232, col 8)
 
$(".redactor, #gb_deal_description, #gb_deal_highlights, #gb_deal_fine_print, #gb_contact_merchant_description").redactor is not a function

Line 24

Comment: @user1790251 What is the `redactor`? library that defines `redactor` is not loaded in your page and it breaks the code.

Comment: Not sure, I will have to look for it since I didn't build this from scratch.  Any possible quick way to find it?

Comment: @user1790251 Check that you don't load jQuery more than once, also that it's loaded before the plugins, open your `functions.php` and you can find the scripts that theme is loading.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3kZq/  Unfortunately I have to get off soon because I have a test in the morning and need to get at least a couple hours of sleep.  I put up the functions.php up in the link, I really appreciate all your help and I will keep working on it for a little while longer.

Comment: I should move the script into the file, not sure where to put it without breaking it though.

Comment: Well, find this function `gbs_theme_register_scripts() {` within this function scripts are registered, you can register your scripts here the way that theme loads the scripts, at wordpress codex you can find the `wp_register_script`.

Comment: Ok so I used Filezilla to upload a file called jquery.nav.js which is basically the code from above.  Now I just need the functions.php to implement it.